# Redirect User after login based on Sharepoint or AD group membership

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

There are two companies. 'Contoso' and 'Contoso-Global' which is a sister company. Now Contoso-Global should use a Sitecollection together with Contoso for working together on a special project. They should not have access to the other Sites and Collections of Contoso.

Contoso runs a Sharepoint Online site as part of its Office 365 account.

Contoso users are populated from AD federated sync. Contoso-Global users are created and maintained directly from within the Office 365 Adminpanel.

Contoso-Global users may not see the content of the Contoso sites and collections. Contoso users may see everything.

Example:
This is the only sitecollection a Contoso-Global use is allowed to access:

```
 https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/contoso-global (or https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/contoso-global/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Startseite.aspx to be precise)
```

On all other URLs, like

```
 https://contoso.sharepoint.com
 https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/project-masterplan/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/default.aspx
```

the Contoso-Global users need to be redirected to the Contoso-Global URL above.

I am a Sharepoint Admin but not a Sharepoint developer. I googled a lot but did not find anything useful. I tried to use a kind of 'Deny Permission' as in Active Directory but I had to learn that Sharepoint does not support this kind of permissions.

I am aware of the Office 365 Guest concept. But due to some limitations of external guests forced us to issue full licenses to the Contoso-Global staff.